# output all of the even numbers from a given ist, one per line

Tags: python, python-2.7

The input is

```
1
2
5
7
8
9
10
end
```

The output I want is `2 8 10`

```
line=raw_input()
lines = []
i = 0
while line != "end":
   lines.append(int(line))
   line=raw_input()
for i in range(len(line)):
    if line[i] % 2==0:
        print line
    i = i + 1
```

Terminal keeps saying not all arguments are converted during string formatting.

Comment: why are you doing `i=i+1`? the `for` loop will take care of changing `i` for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter` here as well.

```
print filter(lambda i:not i%2,map(int,x.split()))
```

where `x` is `1 2 5 7 8 9 10`.

Output:
         `[2, 8, 10]`

Answer (score 0):

1) The

```
for i in range(len(line)):
```

should be

```
for i in range(len(lines)):
```

2) The

```
if line[i] % 2==0:
```

should be

```
if lines[i] % 2==0:
```

3) Also, you don't need to increment `i` since the `for` loop is already doing this for you.

Finally, a slightly more concise way to write that loop is:

```
for line in lines:
    if line % 2 == 0:
        print line
```

Comment: when do use range then?

Answer (score 0):

Your code could be considerably shorter. The following works but does not handle errors:

```
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    if 'end' in line: break
    if not int(line) & 1: sys.stdout.write(line)
```